# select a vaule using jdbctemplet

Tags: java, sql, spring-jdbc

am new to Spring-jdbc

my query is like :

```
select status from myTable where id = 10;
```

I want to execute this query using `JdbcTemplet` which is available in spring jdbc
and get a retrun value and store it in a variable;

```
public class myClass extends JdbcDaoSupport
{
  public void getstatus()
  {
   String sql = "select status from myTable where id = 10";
   String Status = this.getJdbcTemplet().executeQuery(sql);
  }
}
```

please suggest correct way to do this using JdbcDaoSupport

Comment: check return-type of your `getstatus()` method. That should be String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-core), it has similar example.

```
String lastName = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
    "select last_name from t_actor where id = ?", 
    new Object[]{1212L}, String.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `queryForObject` to get back a `String`.

```
String status = this.getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(
"SELECT status FROM myTable WHERE id = ?", String.class, Integer.valueOf(10));
```